# How to detect whether GPS signal is weak or high?

Tags: android

How to detect GPS signal strength such as low (weak) or high ?

is there an API class ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getAccuracy()` method of the Location object returned by `onLocationChanged` provides a good indication of how good the "fix" is.

Answer (score 5):

```
GpsStatus. getSatellites();
//for each of those do 
GpsSatelite. getSnr();
//that ruturns the signal to noise ratio
//use with
GpsStatus.Listener
```

Heres the api docs:
[Location manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) - [GpsStatus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html) - [GpsSatelite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsSatellite.html)

Comment: Watch out for the sat count, though. Often when I go indoors I see the sat count go up, but the accuracy go down. Must be due to reflections or something.

Comment: How much are you willing to pay me?

Answer (score 0):

The Package `geolocator` from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) is needed.

Function to get `LocationAccuracyStatus`:

```
getLocationAccuracy() async {
    LocationAccuracyStatus accuracyStatus =
        await Geolocator.getLocationAccuracy();
    if (accuracyStatus == LocationAccuracyStatus.reduced ||
        accuracyStatus == LocationAccuracyStatus.unknown) {
      //Bad Signal
    } else {
      //Good Signal
    }
  }
```